# send sms/ make call to selected coredata attibute

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, call, ibaction

I want it so that the user can click send sms or make call to the contact selected from the address book I made. The info is all held to the core data element "people" with attribute "cellnumber" for the cell number

```
    - (IBAction)text:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: @"sms:@1231231234"];
}
```

So that works to send it to that arbitrary number (i think it does :s , no iphone to test on) but how do i make it send to the value defined in key "cellnumber"

same with making a call

```
    - (IBAction)call:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1231231234"]];
}
```

i want it to call the attribute for the opened contact in "cellnumber"

Thank you !

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is `NSString *cellNumber = [people valueForKey:@cellnumber"]` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Larme   I want it so that when the user clicks the call button the number it uses is from the cell key in the database

Comment: so redirect to the default Messages app and send text message to specified number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to combine all of the bits of info you have:

```
NSURL *telUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:self.selectedContact.cellnumber]];
```

Replacing `self.selectedContact.cellnumber` with whatever attribute the selected person is stored in. Then ask the application to open that URL:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telUrl];
```

Comment: how do i use *telUrl variable to initiate a call? like call that telUrl variable?

Comment: so say for sending an sms what would differ? also thanks so much btw definitely best answer ! @wain

Comment: Just change 'tel' to 'sms'.